# What if I remove default test cases from a very big Angular Project?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an enterprise level Angular 5 application. I have created most of the components and services using the Angular CLI. So all of them have spec files and the default test case 'Component/Service should be created'.

I am planning to remove all the default test cases since I think they do not test/check anything special that my custom tests do not.

Is there any problems that I cannot foresee right now with the removal of those default test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these tests simply check that the component/service is **defined** (truthy).